# What currency is Active Shipping using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemerchant

I need to calculate UPS shipping rates in a Rails app. I'm attempting to do this with the active_shipping gem from the creators of Shopify. Unfortunately, the documentation is nonexistent.

The particular problem I'm having is determining the currency that active_shipping is using (or even knowing how to change it). As an example, the rate for a small, lightweight box shipped via UPS Ground is "6242". 6242 what? It certainly isn't US dollars. Under the assumption that it is cents, dividing by 100 still returns an unrealistic price.

Can someone who has used active_shipping shed some light on this?

Comment: Look in `x.rate_estimates[0].currency` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following lines

- https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/shipping/rate_estimate.rb#L19
- https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/shipping/rate_estimate.rb#L19

they seems to be cents.

Comment: It is cents, but OP was looking for the currency used.